# Why doesn't RectTransform.GetWorldCorners() employ any camera?

Tags: unity, c#, camera, transformation, unity-ui

Typically, conversion methods from world to screen coordinates and vice versa use a camera to perform these calculations, so I'm wondering how does `GetWorldCorners` method manage without a camera?

---

The second related question concerns the decompiled version of `RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint` method:

```
public static Vector2 WorldToScreenPoint(Camera cam, Vector3 worldPoint)
{
    if (cam == null)
    {
        return new Vector2(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);
    }

    return cam.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPoint);
}
```

Why does it return the same vector if the camera is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you have two questions, you should post each one separately. But since these are easy, I'll knock them out together.

---

**First: why does `GetWorldCorners()` not require a camera?**

> Typically, conversion methods from world to screen coordinates and vice versa use a camera to perform these calculations

That's true. but `GetWorldCorners` is *not* a conversion method that maps between world and screen coordinates, so that does not apply here.

[Let's look at what the docs say about this method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html):

> `public void GetWorldCorners(Vector3[] fourCornersArray);`
>
> **Description**
> Get the corners of the calculated rectangle in world space.
>
> Each corner provides its world space value. The returned array of 4 vertices is clockwise. It starts bottom left and rotates to top left, then top right, and finally bottom right. Note that bottom left, for example, is an (x, y, z) vector with x being left and y being bottom.

Note that the words "screen" or "camera" appear nowhere here. This method has nothing to do with *any* camera's *view* of a `RectTransform`. It just tells you where the corners of that rectangle object are in the world coordinate system of your game - the coordinate system that your cameras *look at* as input, not the screen space coordinates they transform content *into*.

It's like asking "Why doesn't Google Maps need to know the shape of my camera lens to tell me the latitude and longitude of a landmark?" - the landmark just is where it is, no matter how you look at it.

Words like "left" and "bottom" here should be interpreted in reference to the `RectTransform`'s local coordinate system. You could have three different cameras looking at the same canvas - one right-side-up, one on its side, and one upside-down, so they'd disagree about which corner is the "bottom left". We use the `RectTransform`'s own coordinate space as the canonical ordering, so we get an unambiguous answer, no matter how the transform has been rotated/scaled/etc.

---

**Second: why does `WorldToScreenPoint` return the input vector unchanged if the camera is null?**

The only case in which it makes sense to get the screen position of a point in a `RectTransform` without a camera is if the canvas is in "Screenspace - Overlay" mode. In that mode, the world space coordinates within the canvas map 1:1 with pixel coordinates on the screen, so there's no conversion needed - just truncate off the z coordinate, and the remaining x and y are already pixel positions in screen space.

In the other canvas modes, "Screenspace - Camera" and "Worldspace", the position where a point ends up on the screen depends on the camera settings, so in those cases it's not valid to pass `null` in place of the camera.

Comment: For some reason, I assumed that `RectTransform` is stored in canvas coordinates. That's why it confused me. Thank you!

Comment: It is stored in local coordinates — that's why you need a function to convert its local coordinates to world coordinates.

Comment: It turned out to be quite unexpected for me that when the size of the orthographic camera is changed, the world corners of the UI elements are also changed. It seems that they are still calculated taking into account the camera, and since this calculation is made immediately after changing the size of the camera they are always known?

Comment: Is this a "screenspace - camera" canvas, or are you talking about resizing the window that a "screenspace - overlay" canvas is rendering to?

Comment: "screenspace - camera"